# Angular - Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value

Tags: angular, ionic2

When an expression's value changes, seldom, this error is thrown and the app fails to respond any longer.

I have in my view this function: `{{generalService.timeFromNow(item.creation_time)}}`

which calls: `moment(timestamp, "X").fromNow()`

Randomly, when time changed from 35 to 36, this error happened.
[image]

If I have another time moving (ticking) minutes, no error is thrown.

This kind of error happens all around my application, and I do not want to micromanage the `ngOnChanges`, as I think Angular should manage it.

Comment: When you use enableprodmode in angular2 this error disappear. Otherwise search for items that change value during changedetection cycle.

Comment: @laser But what is the rational behind having this error? why is it a problem to change during change detection

Comment: I have one example from my experience: I had a directive [focusme]="true" for one element (and it turned out another). When the component was parsed and run, it rendered two directives for two different inputs, and changed focus first for one, then for another input and reported this exactly error, saying that value changed during rendering (when normally it should not). After this error I figured out my mistake =)

Comment: Without component code and template it is impossible to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of Angular2 in Development mode to help detection of bad designs. Having this error shows that you probably have to redesign.

For example assume you have two fields with this binding. like a text and a graph.

> {{generalService.timeFromNow(item.creation_time)}}

they can end up showing different values in Prod every now and then if you don't address this issue. That would be really difficult to notice in your normal testing and only a small portion of your users will notice it.

The solution is usually to store the result of 'timeFromNow' in some state variable, so that it can not change over the update cycle.